# How to convert .tiff file into windows font .fnt file using code

Tags: python, java, c#, windows, fonts

I have a .tiff file that was created from a .Png file using C#,

But now I need to transform this .tiff file into .fnt file that is the deprecated windows font file,

I didn’t see some library or option to convert it using C# or another languages like python, Java, etc.

Comment: I don't think that's possible since .fnt (like any font format) will require a certain data structure like a glyph/character table, metrics, mapping/encoding data etc. Such a software would need to automagically tell which part of an image is a certain character (something like a OCR + automated font data generation). Fontlab had a program "scanFont" - but I think it's discontinued. Could you post this image (so the original png)?

Comment: Hi @herrstrietzel in this case the PNG must be converted to can used in a printer that require this format for print  PCL files. The png is saved as a macro in the flash memory of the printer as PCL, but to have this PCL file, firstly is required the .fnt file

Comment: pardon me, I was unclear about the main issue: you just can't expect any converter to compile/transpile any raster image (whether its png, tiff, jpg etc. ) to a (bitmap) font file like .fnt – fnt even though used for bitmap fonts is more complex and not just a sprite.  So it's crucial to see your bitmap image to decide if there is any chance to apply an automated conversion.

Comment: FNT isn't a complicated format. You can write a converter yourself easily. Open bitmap. Crop the glyph as a separate bitmap. Write the glyph bitmap to FNT. Repeat until done. Here's my code from 90's dealing with this format: https://github.com/ssg/fatalvision/blob/fe4b0e8dcd4b2e12a1627a1f5ddaee5277cfa3cd/src/loaders.pas